# Angular dependency doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, dependencies

I am new with angular and i need your help to understand what's is my problem :)

I created a simple app.js like this one :

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module('teamStats', []);

    app.directive("header", function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
           templateUrl: "header.html"
        };  
    });  
    app.controller('TeamController', function(){});  
})();
```

Here there is no dependency, i just get my header in index.html thanks to the code below and that is working !!! WOOT i am so happy !

Now i want tu put the directive calling my header in another file called : template.js

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module('template-directives', []);

    app.directive("header", function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: "header.html"
       };
    });
})();
```

My app.js is now like this :

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module('teamStats', ['template-directives']);
})();
```

My header doesn't appear in my index.html i don't understand why .. my dependency is not correctly set ? i forgot something ?

If someone can help ;) it would be really nice !
Thanks for all !!

Best regards,
CUETO Vincent

Comment: Something else is wrong with your code, which is not evident from what you posted. Here's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zC4NhynRQxa0WW2QTU65?p=preview) with your code working.

Comment: That is working on the plunker with my own code so is it WAMP that is not working well ???

Comment: Do you receive any errors?

Comment: The problem is in my index i am searching why this is not working could you take a look on my index in plunker ? [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/zC4NhynRQxa0WW2QTU65?p=preview)

Comment: Put template.js ahead of app.js.

Comment: Already done :s and its not working but i udated the non working index in the plunker

Comment: What's the link to the plunker? (Also, put your index.html in the question instead of as the answer)

Comment: [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/b8TkeXvR3GdoiF0KxWla?p=preview) sorry it was the wrong link

Comment: well, clearly the code in your plunker doesn't work since the script url is `js/app.js`. In the plunker there is no `js` folder. I suggest you re-review your code for errors or build from ground-up from a working example I gave.

Comment: xD ok it's working so ... i come back to the fact it's wamp that cause the problem

Answer (score 0):

You haven't registered any controllers in final version of your app

It should be like this;

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module('teamStats', ['template-directives']);

    app.controller('TeamController', function(){}); 
})();
```

If this doesn't solve your problem please share your index.html

Comment: The directive is resolved without the controller-defining function - this is not the problem.

Comment: I just don't understand why when i had the dependency my web site crash. There is nothing else about angular in my app.js ^^

Answer (score 0):

Check that you include files in index.html in right order:
1. Angularjs lib
2. Your app and modules

Did you forget controller?

```
app.controller('TeamController', function(){});
```

Answer (score 0):

My index is like this :

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title>Ranked Team Stats</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Icon barre d'adresse -->       
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/logo.png" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">        
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

    <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/template.js"></script>
</head>
```

in my body i put :

```
<body ng-app="teamStats">
```

to call my app.js